# What is the best practice to save a quiz answers with different data types in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database, database-performance, entity-attribute-value

**UPDATE: part 1- start:**

We want to get our customers data, but which kind of data? they are not specified! actually we want to have a dynamic application that the admin can define new questions (he can set the answer's data type, length, and other rules) and he also can deactivate old questions!

(I don't want to use EAV schema design, but I can't find the alternative way)

**UPDATE: part 1 - end:**

so I decided to create a quiz application, admin can define questions which their answers data type can be different!

**Example:**

*question ID 1* : what is you name?  *answer*: John **(varchar)**

*question ID 2* : how old are you? *answer*: 25 **(integer)**

*question ID 3* : how much is your salary per hour? *answer*: 30.65 **(decimal)**

*question ID 4* : describe yourself? *answer*: I'm so kind ... **(text)**

**UPDATE: part 2 - start:**

to save the answers it comes to my mind 3 choices:

**UPDATE: part 2 - end:**

1. create a table like this (EAV schema design):

```
    Table profile_answers
    id int [pk, increment]
    question_id int
    profile_id int
    answer text
```

as you see I've save all answers as **text**!
I know that it works, but is it the best way? actually this app is going to have millions of answers and we want to analyze the answers by machine *(for example: getting customers average age, getting married customers, customers with salary > 30.52 and etc)* so I want to implement the way with the best **performance**!

2. create a table like this (EAV schema design):

```
Table answers
id int [pk, increment]
question_id int
profile_id int
integer_value int
decimal_value decimal
varchar_value varchar
boolean_value boolean
longtext_value longtext
```

now I can save data in the proper field and put **NULL** in the other fields (the answer's data type will be determined while defining it's question)

For example:

```
question ID 1 : what is you name? answer: John (varchar)

id 1
profile_question_id 1
profile_id 1
integer_value NULL
decimal_value NULL
varchar_value John
boolean_value NULL
longtext_value NULL

 ----------------
question ID 2 : how old are you? answer: 25 (integer)

id 2
profile_question_id 2
profile_id 1
integer_value 25 
decimal_value NULL
varchar_value NULL
boolean_value NULL
longtext_value NULL

 ----------------
question ID 3 : how much is your salary per hour? answer: 30.65 (decimal)

id 3
profile_question_id 3
profile_id 1
integer_value NULL
decimal_value 30.65
varchar_value NULL
boolean_value NULL
longtext_value NULL
```

**UPDATE: part 3 - start:**

3. when admin adds a new question, I can add a column to answers table (change table's schema) [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60351427/is-changing-database-schema-in-control-panel-by-admin-not-while-development-a)

**UPDATE: part 3 - end:**

It's all about **performance**! what's the best way?
If none of them is not the best one and **I should redesign the database** what is the correct database design?

Comment: If the performance during analyzing is your priority then use variant 2. Of course you may fill only answer datatype field, or all fields with compatible datatype (string - in text only, date - in text and date, integer - in text, decimal and integer, ...).

Comment: @Akina so do you confirm the second way is the best solution?

Comment: If you focus on your priorities, yes.

Comment: EAV schema design is a nightmare.  Condolences.

Answer (score 1):

**Non-EAV**

What is the datatype for?  The user typed the Answer as a *string*; he did not specify the datatype, did he?  That avoids EAV -- Just store strings.  At that point, the `question` can simply be a `TEXT` column in one table.  And the `answer` a column in another table, such as the `profile_answers` you proffered.

As for queries like "getting customers average age, getting married customers, customers with salary > 30.52", you are stuck with table scans, whether it is EAV or not.  The non-EAV approach will be more efficient since there are fewer hoops to go through to get to the value.

You have a `Customers` table; one row per customer, with birthdate as a column.  Average age involves reading that column and doing some simple arithmetic.  Ditto for marital status and salary.

In other words, the UI has a `<form>` that asks about "customer info".  (And other forms that ask about other stuff.)  Then answers for one customer goes directly into a table designed specifically for customer info.

You *could* have that form and the table be "table-driven".  But that is unnecessarily complex.  If, as I first understood you Question, you are building a classroom app that involves test-taking with hundreds of questions, that might lead to something table-driven.

**EAV**

If you do stick with 5 datatypes, then you have these tough questions:  How much precision in your `DECIMAL`?  If the Question is "What is the value of pi", then how do you handle this variety:  3.14, 3.1416, 3.14159, 3.14159265358979, 22/7, "about 3.14", etc?  Only `VARCHAR(...)` or `TEXT` handles those.

What did you mean by "(for example: getting customers average age, getting married customers, customers with salary > 30.52 and etc)" ?  If you mean that the user typed in "30.52", then it works fine to put that into a `TEXT` column and generate the query

```
with salary > "30.52"
```

That is, numeric value can be fed into queries as strings; the datatype does not need to match.  (However "22/7" would be treated as 22, and "about 3.14" would be compared as 0.)

Millions of rows -- Will you be looking through all of them at once?  Very often?  If you have 50 students answering 40 questions, that is a paultry 2000 Q&A to go through at a single time; not millions.

Comment: What is the datatype for? when the admin is creating the question, he can set the answer's data type, length , and other rules! so when a user is answering, all rules related to that question will be checked and the answer will be validated! "That is, numeric value can be fed into queries as strings" I know that, but the point is the performance while I'm working with lots of rows and queries!

Comment: " If you have 50 students answering 40 questions": they are not students! they are our customers, they are more than 100000 quiz's which each of them has more than 40 questions per day! :) it's gonna be increased! we want to analyze each of them when they complete their quiz!

Comment: I've Updated the question

Comment: @soheilyo - I rewrote my first paragraph into several paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

Relational databases work best when you know the schema at design time. Your requirement is one where the schema (for each quiz) is known aonly at run time.

EAV seems like a work around - and it does, indeed, allow you to *store* the data. But querying it very quickly becomes almost impossible - imagine trying to find all customers over the age of 32 who earn between 20 and 30K and who are getting married. Using appropriate data type will help, a little, but your queries will rapidly become extremely complex and, and impossible to optimize.

The good news is that most database engines support either XML or JSON documents, with pretty good query performance. MySQL does [JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) pretty well, for instance.

I would model my system using the major concepts as relational entities (customer, quiz, question), and store the answers as JSON in MySQL.

Comment: thank you, I'll check MySQL JSON, what's your idea bout this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60351427/is-changing-database-schema-in-control-panel-by-admin-not-while-development-a

Answer (score 0):

According to the official MySQL documentation about [String Type Storage Requirements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings) a TEXT data type requires L + 2 bytes, where L is the length of the string. So, if the answer given is the numeric value 100 it will use 5 bytes.

Whereas, according to the docs entry about [Numeric Type Storage Requirements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-numeric) the same numeric value (100) would only take a single byte when using the TINYINT datatype (max 255) or 2 bytes when using SMALLINT type (max 65535)

So, if you are storing a large number of rows in your table, the storage can be upto 5 times greater for values less than 256 when saved as TEXT.

For higher values the storage different becomes much greater:

60000 as TEXT = 7 bytes
60000 as SMALLINT = 2 bytes

I would recommend that you restructure your data model so that the data is stored with the correct type. This will also ensure indexing is more performant, String/Numeric functions work correctly and App level abstraction layer components such as [Doctrine, will map to the correct language type](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.10/reference/types.html) in PHP, etc.

[Here is a good article](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-mysql/9781449332471/ch04.html) about optimizing MySQL data model design.

Comment: do you recommend to use variant 2? or both of them is not good enough?

Comment: you should really assess the type of data you will be storing, if the data is numberic and will always be less that 256, for example, then it makes sense to use TINYINT which used just 1 bytes. 

You can see the full table here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-numeric

Comment: thank you, but I don't know what is the correct database structure to assess the type of data I will be storing!

Comment: Based on your two variants, the second is better as it stores the correct datatype. This means indexing will be more performant too. But, there may be a better way to design the data structure. This will depend on your abstraction later within your application.  Check out this link: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-mysql/9781449332471/ch04.html

Comment: I've added a couple more resources to the answer for you to take a look at.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, someone else must have thought it was a poor question; but I have tried to help :)  If my answer has been useful, consider accepting it as the correct one. All the best, Mat

Comment: If each of the 5 columns is `NULLable`, then the total size is pretty close to the number of characters in the Answer.

Comment: Yes @RickJames I agree. That is why I's suggest redesigning it. But, the question was which is best of the two variants; hence my answer. But, ultimately my view is that the design is wrong. But, that's a different question.

Comment: @matwr I've Updated the question: If none of them is not the best one and I should redesign the database what is the correct database design?

Comment: I think you’d need to post that as a new question

Answer (score 0):

Having NULL values is never a good practice. In point 2. you have 8 columns and 4 of them are NULL. Adding the column for each answers's data type is bad practice.

Having a column with a string data type is a workaround to solve adding nullable columns for each answer's data type.

You will get better performance with 2. approach.
If you need even better performance, you can go with a separate table for each answer data type.

I had experience with quizzes and forms. We need to have rules for conditional showing page, question ... We discussed a lot and I had trouble to convince team that we should switch to JSON or something like that (NOSQL). Relation database is not intended to solve this kind of problems.

Right way would be to separate quiz questions and answers from statistics.
You should move questions, answers, rules and that kind of stuff to NOSQL. Answer and question statistics should be in the relational database.

Comment: this sentence "Answer and question statistics should be in the relational database" does not contrast with "You should move questions, answers, rules and that kind of stuff to NOSQL"?

Comment: *Having NULL values is never a good practice.* The statement is more than doubtful.

Comment: regarding contrast: I meant that quiz definition, question definition, answer's values should be in NOSQL. Statistics, (for example: getting customers average age, getting married customers, customers with salary > 30.52 and etc) should be in SQL. Please note that you need to have logic to extract statistics from question/answer to SQL.

Comment: regarding null values: To be more precise, it is ok to have null column only in case if more than 90% of rows have values for that column.
Other cases: move to new table.

Comment: `NULL` saves space.

Comment: I've Updated the question

Comment: So, when the admin adds a new question, you will add columns... NOSQL database is for that. I never heard/see that user action adds a column to database in SQL (relational) database. Also, the suggestion I gave to you is accepted practice. I think that some of known questionare services keeps question/answers/rules definitions in mysql only because is too much work to switch to NOSQL. Your question should contain statistic definition which will tell system what to extract to statistics database.

Comment: Write a query to imagined statistic table to have a better idea what I am talking about. 
For example:
count married customers. : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM scorevalue WHERE scorename = "married" AND value = 1;
average sallary: SELECT AVG(value) FROM scorevalue WHERE scorename="salary";
statistics database should have tables like this: customer, score, scorevalue ....

Comment: Think also about this. With this requirement you will hit a wall (or probably spend a month trying to get result) with mysql. This kind of requirement will be required.
We need a list of users which are married, have more than 2 kids and age <25.
Or this: There are 10 possible answers in question. If user answers 1 or 2 or 3 (which is group called "bad"), ask additional questions. We need to list "bad" customers.
I would separate definitions from statistics as I said. Otherwise, you will get into unmanagable mysql database and you will write a query for each requirement (.